# Convert a list of lists to 3D list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I got a list of lists (I don't wanna say a 2D list because it has different sizes)

```
mylist = [[0, 4, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0, 4, 1], [0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0,1]] #len(mylist) = 6
```

And I want to convert this list of list to a "3D list" every third element so I would get

```
newlist = [[[0, 4, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0, 4, 1]], [[0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

Maybe it's a pretty basic question and I think I can do this using Numpy, but I'm trying to learn list comprehension and every example I seen so far it has the same amount of elements in every list, thank you in advance, and sorry if it's a simple question.

Comment: No necessarily, mylist can have I don't know, 9 elements that I can divide by 3 or 15 elements and I can divide by 3 or 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every example I seen so far it has the same amount of elements in every list,

That is because many present examples such that it takes an element from a source list, converts it (map it), and constructs a new transformed list. You can also have a conditional in list comprehension that will drop elements from destination list if a certain condition about the item being processed isn't met. [You may want to see my other answer about list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37869704/227884)

---

There's one item to note: The "dimension" or shape of your list doesn't change when put through **simple** list comprehension. You might need to nest it, at the very least. Something like `[[y for y in x] x for x in z]` But if you insist on using it, you'll have to explore using:

- Chunking (this is pretty standard; just search for "chunking python list" here)
- Or, a slightly more evil option: Zip 3 references to the same iterator together. ;)

To answer your question: I see no need for list comprehension. Just plain old slide and list append:

```
newlist = [mylist[:3]] + [mylist[3:]]
print(newlist)
# [[[0, 4, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0, 4, 1]], [[0, 2, 1], [0, 3, 4, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

.. note that the above is not a general solution by any stretch. You'll most likely want one of the two points above.

---

Here's a slightly more general solution. If you're learning about List Comprehension, it might take you a while to fully understand why this works :)

```
>>> items = list(range(20))
>>> it = iter(items)
>>> items_in_one_chunk = 4
>>> iters = [it] * items_in_one_chunk
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*iters)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: Thank you! And yes this was an example, I was looking for a more general solution but I can't get my head working

Comment: Thank you!, I was able to do it using this                                                                       
newlist = [mylist[i: i+n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)] where n is the number of slices I wanna do

Comment: Now, that you've found a way, I'll update the answer with what I said was evil. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the slice() function for splitting your list every 3 elements. Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp#:~:text=The%20slice()%20function%20returns,slice%20only%20every%20other%20item.) for understanding its logic. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570740/python-split-a-list-into-sub-lists-based-on-index-ranges) discussion is similar to what you want to achieve.