# How to divide list according to index position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a combined list of `lat`, `lon` and `alt` in a sequence as shown below, now I want to divide the list into 3 parts 1st for `lat`, 2nd for `lon` and third for `alt`.

```
coords = [48.92504247289378, 9.147973368734435, 29707, 48.92504291087322, 9.147998449546572, 29707, 48.9250463088055, 9.148013780873235, 29707, 48.92505484289239, 9.148021595289876, 29707, 48.925070689333246, 9.148024125370592, 29707]

#list format = [lat,lon,alt,lat,lon,alt.....]
```

**excepted output:**

```
lat = [48.92504247289378,48.92504291087322,48.9250463088055....]
lon = [9.147973368734435,9.147998449546572, 9.148013780873235...]
alt = [29707,29707,29707,...]
```

I tried:

[Split a python list into other "sublists" i.e smaller lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists)

[Python: Split a list into sub-lists based on index ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570740/python-split-a-list-into-sub-lists-based-on-index-ranges)

[Split a list into parts based on a set of indexes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198512/split-a-list-into-parts-based-on-a-set-of-indexes-in-python)

And a few other solutions, but none of them worked.

Can anyone help me to get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slicing the list would work:

```
coords = [48.92504247289378, 9.147973368734435, 29707, 48.92504291087322, 9.147998449546572, 29707, 48.9250463088055, 9.148013780873235, 29707, 48.92505484289239, 9.148021595289876, 29707, 48.925070689333246, 9.148024125370592, 29707]
lat = coords[::3]
lon = coords[1::3]
alt = coords[2::3]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
l = [48.92504247289378, 9.147973368734435, 29707, 48.92504291087322, 9.147998449546572, 29707, 48.9250463088055, 9.148013780873235, 29707, 48.92505484289239, 9.148021595289876, 29707, 48.925070689333246, 9.148024125370592, 29707]
res = [[*l[i::3]] for i in range(3)]
```

The outputs are:

```
>>> res[0]
[48.92504247289378, 48.92504291087322, 48.9250463088055, 48.92505484289239, 48.925070689333246]
>>> res[1]
[9.147973368734435, 9.147998449546572, 9.148013780873235, 9.148021595289876, 9.148024125370592]
>>> res[2]
[29707, 29707, 29707, 29707, 29707]
```

Another possible solution using `numpy` is:

```
import numpy as np
l_np = np.array(l)
n = 3
res = l_np.reshape(int(l_np.shape[0]/n), n).T

print(res)

array([[4.89250425e+01, 4.89250429e+01, 4.89250463e+01, 4.89250548e+01,
        4.89250707e+01],
       [9.14797337e+00, 9.14799845e+00, 9.14801378e+00, 9.14802160e+00,
        9.14802413e+00],
       [2.97070000e+04, 2.97070000e+04, 2.97070000e+04, 2.97070000e+04,
        2.97070000e+04]])
```

Where each row in the `res` matrix is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```py
lat = []
lon = []
alt = []

for i in range(len(coords)):
   if i % 3 == 0:
      lat.append(coords[i])
   elif i % 3 == 1:
      lon.append(coords[i])
   else:
      alt.append(coords[i])
```